# Activex control not display properly in ie

Tags: c#, asp.net, activex

hi i am using activex control in my asp.net application.

I add a reference of dll and write code

object id="vb" name="vbvbnv" classid="Bin/ClassLibrary5.dll#ClassLibrary5.UserControl1"

but when i run it's shows me output like this

http://screencast.com/t/ii87CY99j

in my activex control i use only button but it is not display there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax that you're showing here is not ActiveX but instead what's called a UserControl. These are disabled in IE8 and later.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/10/09/dotnet-usercontrols-do-not-load-in-ie8-internet-zone.aspx

Generally speaking, you should not write code to run inside IE in .NET languages.

Answer (score 0):

ActiveX is a client-side code, so it needs to be installed on client's machine.

You should pack it as described here: [Packaging ActiveX Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751974%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).